# How to package qt application?

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I have made a qt application.
What is the easiest way to give it to someone else ? If I just give the executable, it doesn't bundle the required dependencies (for example, I get: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory).

Is there an easy tool to bundle the required libraries, or to make use of the package management system (that is to say, a tool that would automatically make a .deb out of the executable) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a `static build` and embed Qt libraries for your specific platform.

- [Build Standalone Qt Application for `Windows`](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows)
- [Deploying Qt Applications `Linux`](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Deploying_Qt_Applications)

Comment: Static builds are nice, but for commercial purposes you need a commercial license.